# How do I send a Sendgrid email using a template and add custom data for the template?

Tags: c#, email, twilio, sendgrid, sendgrid-templates

I can send a simple email, I can also send emails using a specific template w/ the TemplateId like the example below, but

**QUESTION** - How do I send this template below and add or include handlebar data (ex. {"name":"Mike", "url":"some_url", "date":"04/18/2022})?

FYI - I can't find any doc that shows any C# examples. I did find this [link to create a transactional template](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/transactional-templates-versions/create-a-new-transactional-template-version) but it doesn't send the email. So not sure here if this is what I'm looking for...

```js
var client = new SendGridClient(Options.SendGridKey);
var msg = new SendGridMessage() {
  From = new EmailAddress(fromEmailAddress, fromEmailName),
  Subject = subject,
  PlainTextContent = message,
  HtmlContent = message,
  TemplateId = "d-30710e173a174ab58cc641nek3c980d4c"
};

var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is that you need to remove the `PlainTextContent` and `HtmlContent` properties to make use of the template. Also, you need to provide a `dynamicTemplateData` object that contains your placeholders.

Here are two code examples that send dynamic template emails [with](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/main/USE_CASES.md#with-mail-helper-class) and [without the helper class](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/main/USE_CASES.md#without-mail-helper-class) (search for `dynamic_template_data` and `dynamicTemplateData`). So the full snippet with the mail helper class would be:

```cs
var apiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("NAME_OF_THE_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_FOR_YOUR_SENDGRID_KEY");
var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
var msg = new SendGridMessage();
msg.SetFrom(new EmailAddress("test@example.com", "Example User"));
msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress("test@example.com", "Example User"));
msg.SetTemplateId("d-d42b0eea09964d1ab957c18986c01828");

var dynamicTemplateData = new ExampleTemplateData
{
    Subject = "Hi!",
    Name = "Example User",
    Location = new Location
        {
        City = "Birmingham",
        Country = "United Kingdom"
        }
    };

msg.SetTemplateData(dynamicTemplateData);
var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
```

PS: Here is the [general API documentation](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/mail-send/mail-send#dynamic-transactional-templates-and-handlebars) that explains the available properties.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Question - are there pre defined handlebar names? If yes, I'm a little unclear on how this works.

Comment: Tbh, I'm not sure but I don't think so.